# How to export csv table in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I try to export .csv table using Powershell but in table i see only 1 field with incorrect value

```
$Users=Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties *
$PCs = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties name, ManagedBy
foreach ($user in $Users)
{
  foreach ($pc in $PCs)
  {
   if ($user.DistinguishedName -eq $pc.ManagedBy)
   {
    Select-Object $user.Name, $pc.Name | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\123.csv' -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8 -Append         
   }
  }       
}
```

But if i use this, its work.

```
$Users=Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties *
$PCs = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties name, ManagedBy
$text =@()
foreach ($user in $Users)
{
  foreach ($pc in $PCs)
  {
    if ($user.DistinguishedName -eq $pc.ManagedBy)
    {
     $text_new = $user.Name + ";" +$user.Department+";"+$user.Company+ ";"+ $pc.Name #| Export-Csv -Path 'D:\123.csv' -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8 -Append
     $text = $text + $text_new              
    }
  }       
 }
$text > D:\123.csv
```

I don't understant why don't work with Select-Object. Can anybody explain me why?

Comment: What makes it the wrong value when exported? Can you double click your csv box, and ensure its just not being exported together?

Answer (score 0):

`Select-Object` is used to select properties **of** an object, i.e. after a pipeline. This should do the trick

```
[pscustomobject]@{Name = $user.Name; PC = $pc.Name} | Export-Csv...
```

See MS Docs for more info

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1